# How to Use AntDesign Icon In React-Native-Elements

Tags: user-interface, react-native, antd

In [React Native Elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/icon.html), there's a link to the [icon directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/). The first library is AntDesign: [Screenshot](https://screencast.com/t/tgY1RJm1FUHy)

In types, they say "type (defaults to material, options are material-community, zocial, font-awesome, octicon, ionicon, foundation, evilicon, simple-line-icon, feather or entypo)". AntD is not included in these. I have tried `type="ant-d"`, `type="antd"`, `type="ant-design"` and `type="antdesign"`. I'd like to waste as little time as possible since this seems to be super straight forward. What am I missing?

Here is a snippet of my code, where I've been adding `type`:

```
render() {
  const { selectedIndex } = this.state
  const buttons = [
    { element: () => <Icon name="notification" type="ant-design" color={ selectedIndex === 0 ? colorsAndFonts.colors.redBalehu : colorsAndFonts.colors.warmGrey } /> },
    { element: () => <Icon name="credit-card" color={ selectedIndex === 1 ? colorsAndFonts.colors.redBalehu : colorsAndFonts.colors.warmGrey } /> },
    { element: () => <Icon name="account-circle" color={ selectedIndex === 2 ? colorsAndFonts.colors.redBalehu : colorsAndFonts.colors.warmGrey } /> },
    { element: () => <Icon name="camera-alt" onPress={ this.takePhoto } color={ selectedIndex === 3 ? colorsAndFonts.colors.redBalehu : colorsAndFonts.colors.warmGrey } /> },
    { element: () => <Icon name="help-outline" color={ selectedIndex === 4 ? colorsAndFonts.colors.redBalehu : colorsAndFonts.colors.warmGrey } /> },
]
```

Of course, I'm just getting a `?` back instead of the icon.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the same issue, I investigated the source code and found the switch statement here which processes the type prop which you provide on the icon.

https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/master/src/helpers/getIconType.js

```
  switch (type) {
    case 'zocial':
      return ZocialIcon;
    case 'octicon':
      return OcticonIcon;
    case 'material':
      return MaterialIcon;
    case 'material-community':
      return MaterialCommunityIcon;
    case 'ionicon':
      return Ionicon;
    case 'foundation':
      return FoundationIcon;
    case 'evilicon':
      return EvilIcon;
    case 'entypo':
      return EntypoIcon;
    case 'font-awesome':
      return FAIcon;
    case 'simple-line-icon':
      return SimpleLineIcon;
    case 'feather':
      return FeatherIcon;
    default:
      if (customIcons.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
        return customIcons[type];
      }
      return MaterialIcon;
  }
```

So, it looks like Ant Design hasn't been added to this helper function yet. Solution is to import it directly as in the other answer, or submit a PR to fix it (I'm submitting a GitHub issue now).

Comment: Thank you for diving into that! I didn’t have time for it so I was really hoping someone else did. Appreciate you submitting the PR too!

Answer (score 5):

You can use like this:

```
    import AntIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign";

...

    <AntIcon name="minuscircleo" color="green" size={50} />
```

BTW this is valid for all libraries